# Click on thumb shows large image

Tags: javascript, onclick, carousel

I have a carousel slider, 
when I click on a thumb an image needs to be loaded in the large banner. 
How can I do this?

It needs to be smooth, it shows a large image, when clicking on a thumb that thumb needs to fade-in over the existing image. But first I need to get it working thow.

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/5zgj227t/8/)

[New other example is here!](http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/w2L92bbt/)

```
  <div class="big">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/476x300&text=first" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/476x300&text=sec" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/476x300&text=third" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/476x300&text=four" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/476x300&text=five" />
  </div>

  <div class="owl-carousel small">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/238x150&text=first" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/238x150&text=sec" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/238x150&text=third" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/238x150&text=four" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/238x150&text=five" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

script:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin: 10,
        responsiveClass: true,
        responsive: {
          0: {
            items: 2,
            nav: false
          },
          600: {
            items: 3,
            nav: false
          },
          1000: {
            items: 4,
            nav: false,
            loop: false,
            margin: 20
          }
        }
      })
    })
```

Comment: I found a good fiddle, all this needs is to fade-in instead of sliding: http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/my86s/26/  

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach an event handler to each image,

I see you are loading jQuery which makes this nice and easy

```
$(function(){
  $(".big img:eq(0)").nextAll().hide();
  $(".es-slides .es-slide-inner img").click(function(e){
    var index = $(this).index();
    $(".big img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
  });    

  $('#basic_slider img').each(function(i,image){
    $(image).on('click', function(){
      $('.big').html('<img src=\''+ image.src + '\'/>');
    });
  });
});
```

We are using the jQuery each method to loop through each image in the carousel, then update the html inside the  with an image tag that has the correct src for the image.

Alternatively you could show/hide the images in the .big container like your html already shows. This will probably work better for fading the images in and out as you wish.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tm10jcu0/)

Comment: I have updated the fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/tm10jcu0/1/ Really need a fade-in / fade-out option thow. thanks so far Alex.